# Self Remove Contributor access from all my Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, rbac

I have been assigned to a lot of Azure subscriptions as a contributor by our customers its more than 200. But I need to remove my contributor access and remove the attachment from their subscriptions. How can I self remove my access or is there any other way I can automate this task without asking the customers one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is no, you can't.

By default [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) role does not give access to granting/revoking permissions and role assignments. Because of this you can't remove yourself (or anybody else).

What you would need to do is contact owner in individual subscriptions and request them to remove yourself. You would also need to contact Azure AD administrators to remove from the Azure ADs associated with these Azure Subscriptions.